# Egad! Tally ambulations nonpreſent on tranſportable æther mechaniſms!

Tags: discussion, down-votes, up-votes, ios

I am reclining at an inﬅitution of youthful learning, waiting to retrieve my heir from his extracurricular exertions, when I determine to entertain myself with the frolicking frippery of delightfully paﬆel uniprong ponies.

Revealing my tranſportable computing mechaniſm I languidly key in the location of this æther repoſitory, and inﬆruct the machine to do my bidding.

Arriving with ſome haﬅe, dᵫ to the local æther artery being of the third era, my mechaniſm tranſlated the æther doſſier into a format which I was able to comprehend.

Unable to contain my enthuſiaſm for the anticipated prancing, I haﬅily incremented the doſſier tally, and pauſed as the machine performed its duty.

The tally increaſed, but my deſire was leﬅ wanting.

Unſatiſﬁed, I made another attempt, this time on a doſſier which I was certain deſerved the attention of other ætherheads.

Dear ſirs, I would tell you something of the diſappƣntment I suﬀered, were it not for the expectation that my ſoul, nay, my very being might forfeit were I to relive the account.

This alone muﬆ ſuﬃce: *The delightfully paﬆel uniprong ponies were not preſent and ambulating as expected.*

I do comprehend the limited reſources with which you are permitted to perform your duties, however this particular tranſportable computing mechaniſm is not uncommon, indeed is has captured a ſigniﬁcant public intereﬅ, and there are many, like myſelf, who conceal one on our perſons both day and night.

I beg you conſider my plea, and rectify this traveﬅy forthwith.

Comment: Hmm. I got a delightfully pastel uniprong pony when I increased the tally of this dossier, so they are not gone. But you get to keep the increased tally anyway.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Perhaps, sir, you are using a different transportable computing mechanism? Mine is of the iOS variety from the Apple establishment.

Comment: @rchern You are correct. Mine is also from the Apple establishment, but not of the iOS variety. I did not notice the ios marker on your dossier.

Comment: Have you ever considered a career in the civil service with [Sir Humphrey Appleby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humphrey_Appleby)?

Comment: @waiwai933 You flatter me sir!

Comment: Dr. Grordbort approves.

Comment: Verily, 'tis the most humor-laden query mine eyes have beheld since this morrow's dawn. Furthermore, I can with great vehemence attest to the veracity and persistence of this most singular phenomenon, being myself in possession of a similar piece of communications machinery.

Comment: Well *my* portable machinery gets to view the whole site (unipronged ponies and all), so clearly it is a problem with Apple...   `:P`

Comment: Upon coming across this bulletin and perusing your words, I am convinced that on me has borne the responsibility to transform this ingenious work of prose into an adaptation of [The Posh Mothershuckling Dangle Dongler Hour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz_K1Gjrx8c).

Comment: @waffles Yea, verily 'tis a bug.

Comment: @waffles - 'Twas indeed a bug. SO (and Meta) were presenting themselves differently upon a particular type of aether-driven portable viewing-device, specifically those begotten of Messrs. Jobs and Wozniak. I'faith, I believe the "bug" designation was neither in error nor jest.

Answer (score 25):

Kind Sir,

Upon learning of your lamentable predicament, I diligently repeated your experimentation on an aether mechanism of my own, only to uncover the fact that said uniprong ponies were indeed ambulatory, contrary to your claim made not several hours previous.

I hereby offer the following photo-representation as evidence of my endeavor.

[image]

Comment: Your most strikingly colored daguerreotype does indeed splendidly prove your truth.

Answer (score 4):

I completely sympathize with your predicament, but I'm not certain it can be ascribed to your use of a particular transportable aether mechanism. I think it may just be a case of shyness on the part of the delightfully pastel uniprong ponies. I have intermittently experienced exactly the disappointment you have so eloquently described, even though my aether mechanism is neither transportable nor of the Apple persuasion.

The good news is that in most cases, I have found that quickly reversing my invoking of the tally, then invoking it again, has convinced the ponies that I mean them no harm, and they have consented to frolic within my humble (and delighting) view.

I console myself that their occasional shyness is meant merely to reinforce our appreciation of the uniprong ponies, and drive home how privileged we are to be graced by their presence.